# Manually expire sessions in WebSphere

Tags: websphere, session-management

Tomcat's manager console allows the user to manually expire sessions. I find this useful for testing session management in applications. So I was wondering if there is a way to do so in WebSphere instead of waiting for the timeout to occur, or changing the configuration (which I sometimes forget to restore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such feature built into WebSphere.